# Is it possible to extend C# object with new variables with Lua/Javascript scripting?

Tags: javascript, c#, lua, scripting

Lets say I have C# class:

```
class Player {
  string Name;
  int HitPoints
}
```

I would like to add modding/scripting support to my game where user would be able to extend it with his own variables. (let say *"bool StartedKill5RatsQuest"*) and then for him it would be same to access both his or default parameters.

User script:

```
player.HP = 10;
player.StartedKill5RatsQuest = true;
```

Is it possible to do it with any well known scripting language?

Comment: No, it is not. You need to use an `ExpandoObject` or something similar.

Comment: You could do this with reflection if you're masochistic

Answer (score 5):

You can't do this directly. However, it is possible to get a similar functionality with introducing an internal set of "variables":

```
Dictionary<string, object> _scriptVariables = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

With this, you can provide your players with a set of methods for creating/getting/settings their "variables", like:

```
public void CreateVariable<T> ( string name, T defaultValue );
public void Set<T> (string name, T value );
public T Get<T> ( string name );
etc...
```

Those methods would access your dictionary and manipulate its values, so your users might write:

```
public void Initialize()
{
    player.CreateVariable<int>("HP");
    player.CreateVariable<bool>("StartedKill5RatsQuest");

    player.Set("HP", 10);
    player.Set("StartedKill5RatsQuest", true);
}

public void Update()
{
     ...
     if(player.Get<bool>("StartedKill5RatsQuest"))
     {
         ...
     }
}
```

This is a bit more verbose then direct member manipulation and you should be smart about types when implementing the support methods inside your class, but it would do the job.

Comment: Just what I was right about to post, I had the same idea with a dictionary of string/object :). You were a bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

As you postet a C#-class as example I can only refer to @rs232's answer.

But if you also accept i.e. javascript (tagged) you can use [prototypes](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp) there.

Prototypes allow objects to add additional properties or even methods outside its main declaration of existing objects.

```
Player.prototype.health = 100;
Player.prototype.heroicName = "Lord";
```

or even add fuctionality:

```
Player.prototype.getHealth = function() { return this.health;}
```

I'm not used in javascript, so please forgive me if I made some syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what rs232 says is the best approach. Generating new properties is just a far too complex and unnecessary way to do this. But if you really really wanted to do it you can look into using the [PropertyBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.propertybuilder.aspx).